# How should I care for a dozen bulbs of Lycoris squamigera?

Tags: plant-health, flowers, bulbs, lily, amaryllis

Someone gave me a box of bulbs, [*Lycoris squamigera*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lycoris_squamigera) (Resurrection Lily), and I don't really know how to care for them. They are in a cardboard box in my basement right now. When I looked up how to care for these, all I could find was that they do not like being dug up. So how should I care for them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether the bulb is sprouted or not, the most important conditions for storing your bulbs are: dry and cold.

The best for the specific summer bulb you mention is between 45-55°F (7-13°C).

The cardboard box is perfect but I'd put some dry material over them to absorb ambient moisture.